# Visual Studio 2013 SQL stored procedure updating a Bit column

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2013

so i have a stored procedure where i need to update a column value to True/False based on another column's being a null or not.

i suppose it needs to be like this:

```
if([Template] is not NULL)
begin
    update CMM_Templates
    set [Template_Exists]=1
    where [ID] = @id
end
```

when trying to update the database, it gives out:

```
An error occurred while the batch was being executed.
```

the table `CMM_Templates` exists, all the columns and the variable exists, the only problem is in the  line:

```
set [Template_Exists]=1
```

if i update the column via a variable, it works. but not if i update it directly.

i have tried:

```
set [Template_Exists]=1
set [Template_Exists]='True'
set [Template_Exists]=cast('True' as bit)
set [Template_Exists]=cast(1 as bit)
```

none of them seems to work.
I'm sure i am missing something, but can figure out what.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1957203.aspx?An+error+occurred+while+executing+batch+Error+message+is+Exception+of+type+System+OutOfMemoryException+was+thrown+

Comment: @almasshaikh yes, because setting a bit's column value will definitely render my entire database server out of memory. can i have something relevant please?

Comment: There is no more detail on the exception? Like `Error message is: ...`. Sql server? The part `if([Template] is not NULL)` is probably wrong, I would understand `if(@Template IS NOT NULL)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand the part
`if([Template] is not NULL)`.

I suggest that you try:

```
   update CMM_Templates
   set [Template_Exists]=1
   where [ID] = @id AND [Template] is not NULL
```